# kotlin script in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-script

I want to run kotlin script in andoird.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val engine = KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine()
        engine.eval("val x =3")
        val result = engine.eval("x+2")
    }
}
```

but i get an error like this:

```
Cannot access 'javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.script.experimental.jsr223.KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

the dependencies i added is:

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:1.7.22"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.7.22"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.7.22"
```

Am i missing some dependencies?

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work on Android for a long time, but some dependencies were never able to run.

Comment: @kotleni it seems ScriptEngineManager is not accessible in android